# How to distinguish multiple overlapping lines on MATLAB graphs?

Tags: matlab, graph, legend, matlab-figure

How can I distinguish multiple overlapping lines on MATLAB graphs like this?

[image]

Comment: you may want to augment the values a bit shifting them e.g. 0.001 points higher/lower? Only in the `scatter` plot, there exists a `'jitter'` option that makes sure that points don't overlie each other

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest different combinations of line widths, marker sizes and colors, plot the thickest lines and largest markers first since the ones plotted later will be on top, this code demonstrates this:

```
x=1:5;
plot(x, x, 'color', 'b', 'marker', 'o', 'markersize', 10, 'linewidth', 1)
line(x, x, 'color', 'g', 'linewidth', 1, 'marker', 's', 'markersize', 5, 'markerfacecolor', 'g', 'linestyle', '--')
```